# How to disable code analysis rule for all callers of a method

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given these two classes:

```
public class Abc
{
   public static void Method(string propertyName) { }
}

public class Def
{
   public int Prop { get; }

   public void Method2() { Abc.Method("Prop"); }
}
```

As is, Roslyn rule CA1507 (use nameof) will be triggered for `Method2`. I don't want that, because that string is used for long-term custom serialization and can never change (if we decide to change the name of `Prop` we won't be changing that string). I don't want to disable the rule on an assembly level or even class level. There are also hundreds of callers like `Def` so I want something that doesn't require me to do anything to the callers.

Is there some kind of [ExcludeParameterFromCodeAnalysis] I can put on the `propertyName` param to be excluded from all or some code analysis?

Here's the concept I hope exists, or some variant on it:

```
public class Abc
{
   public static void Method([SuppressMessageForCallers("CA1507")]string propertyName) { }
}

public class Def
{
   public int Prop { get; }

   public void Method2() { Abc.Method("Prop"); }
}
```

Comment: If you added a new `const string Bob` which is set to `"Prop"` and you use that instead, does it give you a warning?

Comment: That's a solution (no warning), but if there's a solution that only involves changing Abc that's ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this rule only [triggers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/ea231a69f9891764f10c5ed214409627da010be7/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/Core/Maintainability/UseNameofInPlaceOfString.cs#L67)<sup>1</sup> when the name of your parameter is `paramName` or `propertyName`<sup>2</sup>. So let's change the parameter:

```
public class Abc
{
   public static void Method(string propertySerializationName) { }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Even if you don't know or can guess at which specific analyzer implements a warning, it looks like searching the [roslyn-analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers) repository for the specific code (`CA1507`) should help you find them without too many false positives.

<sup>2</sup>Weirdly, it wouldn't even appear to trigger on a parameter called `parameterName`.

Comment: Beautiful. I was banging my head trying to find a simple one-line solution and this is 100% it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that can be done to `Abc.Method` declaration regarding this warning because the warning is not on the method (or even on it's invocation) but on the literal itself.

It might be ugly, but it works:

```
public class Abc
{
   public static void Method(string propertyName) { }
}

public class Def
{
   public int Prop { get; }

   public void Method2()
   {
#pragma warning disable CA1507 - use nameof
       Abc.Method("Prop");
#pragma warning restore CA1507 - use nameof
   }
}
```

Visual Studio will offer that on the light bulb or screwdriver menu on the left gutter.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, they're asking for something they can do to `Method` (or, at the least, inside `Abc` maybe) so that *any* new code that looks like `Method2` doesn't need to do anything, such as these pragmas.